# Add Additional User Roles to Roadkill Wiki

Tags: windows-authentication, wiki, roles, roadkill-wiki

I am using Windows Authentication for Roadkill Wiki.  Has anyone attempted to add additional user roles in Roadkill Wiki for fine grain access control?  If so, do you have any guides to help with this.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can't add additional user roles in Roadkill Wiki. You can find proof of this fact in [documentation](https://github.com/roadkillwiki/roadkill/blob/master/docs/users-and-permissions.md):

> Roadkill has just **two types of user roles**: editors (or standard users) and admins. The only difference between the two is that admin users who belong to the admin role can access the "site settings" page, delete and lock pages.

Also you can find authentication implementation details in [code](https://github.com/roadkillwiki/roadkill/blob/4a2f1706950fcb1176f91ec9d4bfdad9497033e9/src/Roadkill.Core/Security/IUserContext.cs):

```cs
public interface IUserContext
{
    // ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets whether the user (if logged in), is in the editors group.
    /// </summary>
    bool IsAdmin { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets whether the user (if logged in), is in the editors group.
    /// </summary>
    bool IsEditor { get; }

    // ...
}
```

You can see that there is no UserRole type. Just two flags: `IsAdmin` and `IsEditor`. Not very flexible :) Of course, you can create an issue or pull request.